How to nest process groups/session?
In Python, I am starting another process procB from within my app procA by using subprocess.Popen with shell=True. procB, started in the shell, can create his own children.
What I already have:

procB and all its children get terminated, when procA gets terminated

I create a new process group for procB and make procB the leader with preexec_fn=os.setsid
If procA recevices a SIGTERM then I send a SIGTERM to procB as well
If procB does not behave, it eventually gets killed after a while



What is still missing:

procB and all its children get killed, when procA (the parent) gets killed (not terminated).

How can I achieve that? Can I have sth like a nested process group? I imagine something like

groupA

procA (leader of groupA)
groupB

procB (leader of groupB)

children's of proc B







Not sure if and how that is possible. Or maybe there is another more obvious way I do not see right now?
I already found this: How to kill a python child process created with subprocess.check_output() when the parent dies?
But, this does not work when using shell=True as it seems.
